# How to use CURL in Model in Magento2?

Tags: php, curl, model-view-controller, model, magento2

I want to use CURL in my Model in Magento2. When I print the response variable its not returning and data.Please help me to find out how to use CURL in Model in Magento2?

Model Code

```
<?php
    namespace Inchoo\Helloworld\Model;

    use \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

    class Orderprocessing extends AbstractModel
    {
        const PROCESSING_ID = 'entity_id'; // We define the id fieldname

        protected $_idFieldName = self::PROCESSING_ID; // parent value is 'id'

        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('Inchoo\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Orderprocessing');
        }

        public function process($order_data = array()){

            if(empty($order_data)){
                return false;
            }
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_URL , $url);
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $response  = curl_exec($ch);
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($response); die;
        }
   }
```

Comment: what is defined in `$url`?

Comment: There are different ways methods for making a Curl call in Magento 2, you can understand via this post [Use Curl In Magento 2](https://www.mageants.com/blog/how-to-use-curl-in-magento-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that argument of method is not empty.
2. Test `curl` with different url.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.You can execute **CURL** via **\Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory** in Magento2.

```
<?php
    namespace Inchoo\Helloworld\Model;

    use \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

    class Orderprocessing extends AbstractModel
    {
        const PROCESSING_ID = 'entity_id'; // We define the id fieldname

        protected $_idFieldName = self::PROCESSING_ID; // parent value is 'id'

        protected $_httpClientFactory;

       /**
         * Initialize resource model
         *
         * @return void
         */
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('Inchoo\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Orderprocessing');
        }

        public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory){
            $this->_httpClientFactory = $httpClientFactory;
        }

        public function process($order_data = array()){

            $url = "https://wwww.example.com/";
            $requestData = array('key' => 'test','password' => 'test@123', 'action' => 'getProduct', 'id' => 1);

            $client = $this->_httpClientFactory->create();
            $client->setUri($url);
            $client->setParameterPost($requestData);
            $client->setHeaders(
                [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                ]
            );

            $response = $client->request(\Zend_Http_Client::POST)->getBody();   
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think  | WARNING | [ ] Direct object instantiation (object of
     |         |     Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl) is discouraged in
     |         |     Magento 2.